# Adding comma to while loop wpquery output

Tags: loop

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',  
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'views',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'=> 'DESC', // sort descending
);

// Custom query.
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check that we have query results.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        printf( '<a href="%s" class="link">%s</a>', get_permalink(), get_the_title());

    }

}

// Restore original post data.
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

This is the first time i've worked with wpquery.

Two questions

1. how do i add a comma each item but the last?
2. How could i've written this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',  
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'views',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'=> 'DESC', // sort descending
);

// Custom query.
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check that we have query results.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        $comma_char = ($query->current_post + 1) < ($query->post_count) ? "," : "";//add comma if not last post
        printf('<a href="%s" class="link">%s</a>' . $comma_char, get_permalink(), get_the_title());

    }

}

// Restore original post data.
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

as for the second question (its 1 question for post by the way), looks like a standard WordPress query, its kind of hard to say how it can be improved without knowing the details about it.

Comment: Im still getting the last comma.

Comment: updated, sorry i was using the wrong variable

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to set up a global post object each time you ask for a title or a permalink. It is always better to search for a solution that doesn't involve globals. :)

For listing that should look like *"Apples, Bananas, and Oranges"*, you can use `wp_sprintf_l()`. It uses a localized special separator for the last item. In English, this is an [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) plus an *and*.

Here is how I would have done it.

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    $links = array_map(
        function( \WP_Post $post ) {
            return sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" class="link">%s</a>',
                get_permalink( $post ),
                get_the_title( $post )
            );
        },
        $query->posts
    );

    print wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $links );
}
```